# In WF 4.0 can a parent workflow stop even when asynchronous child activities are still running?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a one main Workflow which calls several activities asynchronously. Some of the asynchronous activities are long running activities, so my concern is can parent workflow can complete the execution state when even the some of the async activities are running or when they are in hydrated state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent workflow may not be actively executing any code itself, but it is going to wait for those async activities to complete before it can move on to its next execution step.

Comment: Hi Drew thanks for reply . I am sending my small code snippet of how I am calling activity asynchronously.